# React-Router: Why can't a hastag (#) be put in a URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

**React-Router: 1.0.0**

I'm using a hash history and **I was thinking of using hashtags as part of the path in the URL(not as a fragment)**, but any path that has a hashtag will instantly be cut off at that point the hash is used.

For instance:

```
this.props.history.pushState(null, `/blah/blah/#blah`);
```

Routes to:
**/#/blah/blah/?_k=pdcm9b**

```
this.props.history.pushState(null, `/blah/#blah/blah`);
```

Routes to:
**/#/blah/?_k=pdcm9b**

```
this.props.history.pushState(null, `/#blah/blah/blah`);
```

Routes to:
**/#/?_k=pdcm9b**

**Question: 
Why does this happen? Can I use hashtags in URLs(like even if I need to switch to createBrowserHistory)?**

Comment: Sure you can, but you have to use the URI encoded form `%23`. Whether your server environment will accept a `#` in the path is another matter entirely

Comment: @PaulS. I've been hunting on the web, but I can't find a good example of escaping the # in Javascript cause I tried this.props.history.pushState(null, `/blah/%23/blah`) and the URL is created was not escaped.